# mgp25 Instagram-API can't upload anymore

Tags: php, api, instagram

mgp25 Instagram-API is great, but… My code was working fine for weeks and then it send me back this message "Invalid request options.".

I have the same problem with uploadPhoto.php sample script.

I try to reload de files.
I try with other Instagram accounts.
On a server, on my computer… I have always the same message.
Any idea?

The official code that is not working anymore (for me):

```php
    set_time_limit(0);
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    /////// CONFIG ///////
    $username = 'xxxx';
    $password = 'xxx';
    $debug = false;
    $truncatedDebug = false;
    //////////////////////

    /////// MEDIA ////////
    $photoFilename = __DIR__."/test.png";
    $captionText = 'Test!!!';
    //////////////////////

    $ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);

    try {
        $ig->login($username, $password);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    sleep(5);

    try {
        $photo = new \InstagramAPI\Media\Photo\InstagramPhoto($photoFilename);
     sleep(5);
        $ig->timeline->uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => $captionText]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    }
```

This code run fine until the upload function.

PS: All my non uploading scripts are working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful here.

Comment: The free version of this library is useless now, you should pay for it!

Comment: Found this https://launchpad.net/instagram-api , in case if need the code

Comment: @BerkantIpek You can sent tweet to author https://twitter.com/_mgp25/